# PHP 7 curl not being loaded

Tags: php, windows, apache, curl, php-7.1

I have installed in my local computer apache 2.4 with PHP 7.1. I enabled curl in my php.ini (extension=php_curl.dll), but for some reason curl is not being loaded even after i enabled it, i made a phhinfo to check, and nothing, i also made a small script:

```
function isExtensionLoaded($extension_name){
    return extension_loaded($extension_name);
}

echo isExtensionLoaded('curl');
```

And nothing, is blank, what it means is not being loaded, is something missing? Im on Windows 10.

Comment: make sure that you've restarted your apache2 server

Comment: "blank" means,  "its loading, but can't display" or "it throws error but error logging is not activated in php.ini" etc....

Answer (score 10):

In my case it worked when I also copied nghttp2.dll to Apache bin directory

Answer (score 7):

I was looking for a solution a really long time, until I decided to read some comments on the PHP documentation site: http://php.net/manual/de/curl.installation.php

I fixed coping the following list files from php folder (in my case C:\xampp\php7)

```
libeay32.dll
libssh2.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

Some people also had to move ***nghttp2.dll*** for it to work.

To your apache/bin folder (C:\xampp\apache\bin in my case).

I also copied those to C:\Windows\System32, but I do not think any of these files were loaded.

***EDIT***: I successfully deleted these dlls from system32 folder and was able to run curl afterwards

Comment: Those three and nghttp2.dll as well, for me. Cheers (also to @nick-proto)

Comment: I can't understand why third-party bundles are so popular yet you apparently always need to do workarounds like this for simple features. In the official PHP binaries curl always works out of the box :-?

Answer (score 1):

It works if you set ssl `VERIFYPEER` to `false`

```
curl_setopt($get, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

it will works fine .
you can also make curl work withe ssl by downloading the  cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
and Adding the cert to your php.ini file

```
curl.cainfo="C:\path\cacert.pem" 
openssl.cafile="C:\path\cacert.pem"
```

and

```
curl_setopt($get, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
```

will work too
this way you can prevent  man-in-the-middle attacks,
check this link for more details http://thisinterestsme.com/php-curl-ssl-certificate-error/

Comment: Thanks, bro!  Your solution helped me with my overlapping problem here:

```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71110013/how-to-enable-curl-locally-on-my-windows-10-so-that-my-php7-localhost-with-or-w?```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have edited the right file. There should be separate file for CLI, Apache2 and other SAPIs. After doing so, restart the Apache2 server.

Answer (score 0):

It hard to guess why its not running and as I see you don't get error atm.

you should get errors but I am pretty sure you didn't set error-logging in your php.ini

First we need to activate logging to see why your extensions are not running correctly:

Please change/add following lines in your php.ini file:

```
display_startup_errors = On
error_log = 'c:/php-logs/php-error.log'
```

Now create the `php-logs` directory and `php-log.log` file

```
mkdir c:/php-logs
copy NUL c:/php-logs/php-error.log
```

Now restart the server. Now you should get the errors and please share the error-code so I can help

Update:

Enable mod_ssl in `httpd.conf``

```
LoadModule ssl_module c:\apache-2.2\modules\mod_ssl.so
```

Comment: Hello is giving me this error: "PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll"

Comment: Its this: extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"

Comment: Can you please check `httpd.conf` file, I guess mod_ssl.so is not installed and check my updated answer please

Comment: Yes, i already enabled, it was comment and i remove the comment :LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so